# Unable to drop a CLR with Error "insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default'"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When i attempt to drop an assembly I receive this error:

```
DROP ASSEMBLY [test.Sql.Clr]
Msg 701, Level 17, State 13, Line 1
There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query.
```

I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1).

The problematic assembly has a blank clr_name when I run sys.assemblies, and contains one dependant assembly that was replaced correctly (the problem occurred when trying to load a newer assembly)

```
select name, clr_name from sys.assemblies
test.Sql.Clr.Models test.sql.clr.models...
test.Sql.Clr
```

Has anyone seen this issue or know how to resolve it?

John

Comment: That does seem odd (that is it blank in sys.assemblies) If I remember right, you should be able to remove the record from this table safely, restart your server (just sql server, not the os) and reload your CLR assembly.  Basically, SQL server loads the DLL on startup and whenever it is updated.

Comment: SQL Server is blocking us from changing sys.assemblies directly (it says direct edits are not allowed to system tables).  Do you have any magic that would let us modify a system table?

Comment: I assume you are right-clicking on the table and trying to "Edit top 200".  You should be able to call "DELETE FROM ..." if your login has the proper rights. (Use administrator or sa)

Comment: I do not sys the sys-assembly_files in Enterprise Manager under Tables\System Tables.  When I try to delete from it using a SQL window (DELETE from sys.assembly_files WHERE assembly_id  = 65542) I get the error "Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed." .  I am a SQL Administrator

Comment: Check out this link for information on how to update system tables.  [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b533994a-f343-46bb-a29e-0c3663138397/ad-hoc-updates-to-system-catalogs-are-not-allowed]

Comment: This worked, thanks Steve - I'll update the question with the steps we followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Steve's help I was able to clean this up as follows:   enabled direct access to system tables using the techniques in the link (start SQL in single user mode using the -m argument, run a sqlcmd in direct to administrator mode using -A flag).  We manually cleaned out all references to the corrupt CLR by looking at sp_helptext on sys.assemblies and sys.assembly_files.  We had to clean quite a few tables, and could not load the assembly properly until they all the corrupt entries were removed.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, can't drop an assembly with a blank clr_name. I deleted from sys.sysclsobjs, sys.sysobjvalues and sys.syssingleobjrefs. The problem I got after that is that I can't create a new assembly. The create query just runs forever.